# Configure trust for search between a SharePoint 2013 farm and a SharePoint 2010 farm

Tags: 2010, 2013, federated-search

I was wondering if it was possible to allow a SharePoint 2013 search app to show results from the index of a SharePoint 2010 farm. I have seen instructions for doing this between two 2013 farms but I am curious if our scenario is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can It. It is do able.

We have SharePoint 2013 Search Farm, which is crawling both 2010 & 2013 farms. All you need make sure Content Access Account have the correct permission on the destination Web App.

Comment: Are you adding the SharePoint 2010 farm as a content source or a results source?

Comment: Content Source.

Comment: What are the steps/procedure to add SharePoint 2010 farm as a Result Source in SharePoint 2013? (No crawl)